# Object selection and Printing from inside class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, extends

I am trying to have a user select an animal from my virtualZoo.java file when it runs. It compiles, but once the user inputs a selection I get an error that reads "Erroneous tree type." The code is below for virtualZoo.java, animal.java, and dog.java. I have created objects below the switch statement as I was instructed to use those, but do not understand the implementation.

**virtualZoo.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VirtualZoo{
public static void main(String[] args) {

                    Animal cat = new Animal("Cat", "Meow");
                    Animal dog = new Animal("Dog", "Woof");
                    Animal duck = new Animal("Duck", "Quak");

    // create Scanner
    Scanner input;
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double userInput;
                    System.out.println("Welcome to the Zoo");
                    System.out.println("Pick select an animal to visit");
        System.out.println("=================================");
        System.out.println("===========MAIN MENU=============");
        System.out.println("=================================");
        System.out.println("==  0) Cat    ===================");
        System.out.println("==  1) Dog    ===================");
        System.out.println("==  2) Duck   ===================");
        System.out.println("== -1) EXIT   ===================");
        System.out.println("=================================");
        System.out.println();System.out.println();
        System.out.println( "Input  : ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        userInput = sc.nextInt();


    switch (sc.nextInt()) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println(cat);
            break;
        case 1:
            System.out.println(dog);
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println(duck);
            break;
        case -1:
            System.out.println("Your name is short length.");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
                    duck.speak();
                    dog.speak();
                    cat.speak();


  }

}
```

**animal.java (Animal Class within virtualZoo.java)**

```
public class Animal {
private String animalSound;
private String animalType = "";

//set animal sound
public void setSound(String sound) { this.animalSound = sound; }

//get animal sound
public String getSound() { return animalSound; }
public void setType(String type) { this.animalType = type; }

//get animal type
public String getType() { return animalType; }


public Animal(String animalType, String animalSound)
{
    this.animalSound = "";
    this.animalType = animalType;
    this.animalSound = animalSound;
}

public void speak()
 {
    System.out.println("The " + animalType + " says " + animalSound);
 }
}
```

**dog.java (Dog class within Animal class)**

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

public Dog(String animalType, String animalSound) {
    super(animalType, animalSound);
}

@Override
public void speak(){

    System.out.println("This dog barks");

  }
}
```

Comment: How are you getting that error? The code posted works fine for me

Comment: Have you learned enums? I'll include them in my answer if so...

Comment: I may need to restart my IDE then if that is the case. Everytime I compile and put in user input I recieved that erroneous tree error

Comment: I have not learned enums yet

Comment: UPDATE The code seems to be compiling now, but I have to enter the user input in twice to get any results. The code still does not produce the desired outcome. Should I possible use a different statement? Possibly If/Then instead of switch.

Comment: No, you have a mistake in your code. I pointed it out in my answer, you're prompting the user for an input twice

Comment: I noticed the int vs. double for user input right before reading this. I will try your suggestions and see if that fixes my issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track but I believe you have some mistakes. I'm assuming the code you posted is slightly different from the code that's giving you the error (I tested, and didn't receive the error)

**Here, you are getting 2 inputs from the user. I believe you meant to get just 1.**

`userInput = sc.nextInt();`
`switch (sc.nextInt())`

Also, `userInput` **should be on type `int`, not double.**

**You have a dog class, but no cat/duck class**

It looks like you might be trying to use a factory pattern, but I'm not 100% sure. You could create an `AnimalFactory` class if so. Otherwise the class 'Animal' is confusing. I'll assume you are not using a Factory Pattern.

You'll notice a few things:

I override the `toString()` method from Object. `System.out.println` will invoke the `toString()` method.

Cat, Duck and Dog all extend from `Animal`, so your `Animal animalSelected` can be of any of these types!

Animal has 2 abstract methods. These methods Must be overriden in any sub classes (Cat, Dog, Duck). Having the methods declared Means we can use the methods inside the Animal class. It also allows us to invoke the methods on any Animals.

E.G you can use `animalSelected.getAnimalSound()` even though Animal does not define a body of that method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VirtualZoo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    // Options
    final int catType = 0,
              dogType = 1,
              duckType = 2,
              exit = -1;

    // create Scanner
    Scanner input;
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput;
                    System.out.println("Welcome to the Zoo");
                    System.out.println("Pick select an animal to visit");
        System.out.println("=================================");
        System.out.println("===========MAIN MENU=============");
        System.out.println("=================================");
        System.out.println("==  " + catType + ") Cat    ===================");
        System.out.println("==  " + dogType + ") Dog    ===================");
        System.out.println("==  " + duckType + ") Duck   ===================");
        System.out.println("== " + exit + ") EXIT   ===================");
        System.out.println("=================================");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println( "Input  : ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        userInput = sc.nextInt();

    Animal animalSelected = null;

    switch (userInput) 
    {
        case catType:
            animalSelected = new Cat();
            break;
        case dogType:
            animalSelected = new Dog();
            break;
        case 2:
            animalSelected = new Duck();
            break;
        case -1:
            System.out.println("Your name is short length.");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (animalSelected != null)
    {
        System.out.println(animalSelected);
    }
}
```

}

```
public abstract class Animal 
{
    public abstract String getAnimalSound();
    public abstract String getAnimalType();

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
       return "The " + getAnimalType() + " says " + getAnimalSound();
    }
}

public class Duck extends Animal 
{
    @Override
    public String getAnimalSound() 
    {
        return "quacks";
    }

    @Override
    public String getAnimalType() 
    {
        return "Duck";
    }

}

public class Cat extends Animal 
{
    @Override
    public String getAnimalSound() 
    {
        return "meows";
    }

    @Override
    public String getAnimalType() 
    {
        return "Cat";
    }
}


public class Dog extends Animal 
{
    @Override
    public String getAnimalSound() 
    {
        return "barks";
    }

    @Override
    public String getAnimalType() 
    {
        return "Dog";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you again. All of those edits worked great. Thank you for explaining the Factory Pattern. I am sure that will come in handy later on down the road.